# How do I get access to the object which the Timer is attached to?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a programming problem which I think is being caused by my rustiness in using events and delegates...

I have the code:

```
public void DoStuff()
        {
            List<IProcess> processorsForService1  = processorsForService1 = ProcessFactory.GetProcessors();

            foreach (IProcess p in processorsForService1)
            {
                if (p.ProcessTimer != null)
                {
                    p.ProcessTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(IProcess_Timer_Elapsed);
                }
            }
        }
```

And:

```
  private void IProcess_Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
            {
                IProcess p = (IProcess)sender;
                p.Step_One();
                p.Step_Two();
            }
```

But when I get to the event handler im getting null reference exception for p on the first line.

How do I pass an argument to the handler in this instance?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. An object does not know which class it belongs to. The sender is the `Timer`, not the `IProcess`

Comment: So how can I pass the p to the event handler? I need to call something in each IProcess class every 5000 milliseconds.

Comment: Why can't each process listen to it's own timer instead?

Comment: How do I send an argument to the Handler basically?

Comment: @Pete2k - I suppose you could inherit Timer and create a new class that sets exposes which Process its connected to.  Of course as others have indicated there is a reason this already not exposed.  There are better ways to go about what you want to do.

Comment: @OskarKjellin, you should add that comment as an answer.

Comment: it's still possible using lambda's, see my answer for more details.

Comment: @Pete2k Then what does DRY have to do with this? You can just create an abstract base class isntead of the interface and then implement the logic there. Alot cleaner and probably a lot less repeating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), if you were to use a [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) then you could pass a `state` object which, in this case, could be the desired instance of a class, i.e. the timer's 'owner'. In this way, you define your method body as with your previous experience of implementation within an event handler, only now the signature is as follows:

```
private void MyTimerCallbackMethod(object state)
{

}
```

Then, upon creating the timer instance, you can do something such as:

```
var timerCallback = new TimerCallback(MyTimerCallback);
var timer = new Timer(timerCallback, myStateObject, 
    Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Then, use `timer.Change(whenToStart, interval)` to kick off the timer.

Answer (score 0):

The sender is the timer object, not the object associated with the handling delegate. For a start, events can have multiple handlers.

What you could do is create a delegate which has access to the `IProcess` using variable capture.

Answer (score 0):

if you used a lambda instead of a delegate you could refer to the class from the lambda because it would still be in the referencing environment. I think this is called [Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)).

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    List<IProcess> processorsForService1 = ProcessFactory.GetProcessors();
    foreach (IProcess p in processorsForService1)
    {
        if (p.ProcessTimer != null)
        {
            p.ProcessTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
            {
                p.Step_One();
                p.Step_Two();
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Beware of the following scope related rules though (taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687(v=vs.90).aspx)):

> The following rules apply to variable scope in lambda expressions:
>
> - A variable that is captured will not be garbage-collected until the delegate that references it goes out of scope.
> - Variables introduced within a lambda expression are not visible in the outer method.
> - A lambda expression cannot directly capture a ref or out parameter from an enclosing method.
> - A return statement in a lambda expression does not cause the enclosing method to return.
> - A lambda expression cannot contain a goto statement, break statement, or continue statement whose target is outside the body or in the body of a contained anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

Make the event handler a member of IProcess and set up like this:

```
p.ProcessTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(p.IProcess_Timer_Elapsed);
```

and if you want to handle the event elsewhere, make the handler forward the event:

```
class IProcess
{
  public delegate void Timer_Elapsed_Handler (IProcess process, ElapsedEventArgs e);
  public event Timer_Elapsed_Handler Timer_Elapsed;

  public void IProcess_Timer_Elapsed (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (Timer_Elapsed != null) Timer_Elapsed (this, e);
  }
}
```